# Make List Columns Read-Only

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, permissions, office-365

I know this isn't supported OOTB but I really have a requirement to make certain columns read only in O365 SharePoint Online (preferably modern experience).

We are trying to encourage a group of users to move from an Excel spreadsheet for managing tasks to using SharePoint. However, they have sheet protection on which prevents users changing due dates / task category etc.

Certain users should be able to edit these "locked" fields but others should not.

I know I could lock the edit fields with PowerApps but what's to stop a savvy user creating their own connection to the list to edit these columns?

Am I going about this the wrong way by using lists? Is there some other solution which would serve me better?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is problematic in Sharepoint as the platform doesn't have an field security concept build in (you would have to use Dynamics CRM for it) there is no real way around it. You can create an smoke and mirror solution but when stored in one list it is impossible to fully block users (they could use web service call, PowerShell PnP to go around you form). What you could do is to create another list that will have the due date/ category and make it a look up to your first list. Give the other list only an read access to all users and write access to limited group.

Another option is to enable versioning so you could see who has updated what in the list to track changes that were not approved.

Comment: Thanks, this actually sounds like a good idea. I think I've been approaching it the wrong way. I might look into making a "Tasks" list with editable task details, comments, etc - then an "Assignments" list where they have read-only access which contains user assignment, due date etc.

Comment: don't forget to upvote a useful answer!  Sharepoint Admin tend to be obsessive reputation points collectors :-)

Comment: In response to your comment clearwater - try addng a look-up column to your Task list and your Assignments list - this will help to connect the items in the two lists that you will have